# Angular sub/child URL's not found only base URL found after deployment to Linux server

Tags: linux, docker-compose, deployment, angular-routing, angular16

Only base url is found no sub/child url is working. I make build locally using `ng build --configuration=dev` command

Here is my docker file:

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:lts
# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
#COPY ./src /var/www/html/

# Expose the port that the Angular app will run on
EXPOSE 9095

# Use a simple web server to serve the static files
CMD ["npx", "http-server", "-p", "9095"]
```